# PrimeNg <component> is not a known element error (@angular-2.0.0 & primeng-1.0.0-beta.16)

Tags: angular, primeng

I started with Angular 2 RC5 and PrimeNG 1.0.0-beta.13 beta. I'm loading PrimeNg components as xModules and has no problems displaying Data Table, Input, SelectItem, Buttons, modals. However, I'm getting this error when I try to use TabView or Accordion.

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'p-accordionTab' is not a known element:

I imported the TabViewModule in the @NgModule. Currently, I updated my app to use Angular 2.0.0 (final) and PrimeNg beta.16 (latest) but still having the errors. I'm using webpack to chunk polyfills, vendor and app codes and I'm seeing accordion and tabview modules in the webpack-generated js files.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance!

Some snippets:

app.module.ts

```
import { 
ButtonModule, 
  DataTableModule, 
  DialogModule, 
  GrowlModule,  
  TabViewModule,
  AccordionModule }  from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
...
imports: [
DataTableModule, 
DialogModule, 
GrowlModule,  
TabViewModule,
AccordionModule
],
...
});
```

template.html (pasted from PrimeNG docs)

```
<p-accordion>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
   Content 1
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
    Content 2
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
    Content 3    
</p-accordionTab>
```

Comment: Have you imported Accordion module in the main module?

Comment: Yes, I did import AccordionModule in app.module.ts. I also tried adding it to the actual module (and component) which calls the template that renders the accordion tags but still no luck.

Comment: Did you found any solutions for this problem @user6850401 ?

Comment: might be a bit late but for some reason, when I rebuilt my local workspace with Angular 2 Final, the error went away.

Comment: I stopped debugging and rebuilt my dotnetcore project and the error went for me too.

Comment: Did you try using `p-accordion-tab` instead of `p-accordionTab` angular doesn't like camel case in templates usually

Comment: can you share the error log, most probably you must have skipped injecting some dependencies. Also as commented below by another user, PrimeNG requires a peer of angular animations module https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup; also you have to add the omega css from ng Module into your resourse.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is primeng need animation package so i just import BrowserAnimationsModule in appModule.

**npm install primeng**

```
npm install primeng --save
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AccordionModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
})
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
       Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
      ],
```

Comment: That was my issue as well!  Thank you!